# Adding Dependency to stack Project?

Tags: haskell

After running:

```
stack new my-project
cd my-project
stack setup
stack build
```

I would like to add the [Conduit](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.13/conduit-combinators-1.1.1/Conduit.html#v:decodeUtf8LenientC) library as a dependency.

I edited the generated, via `stack new`, `stack.yaml` to have:

```
extra-deps: 
- conduit-1.2.10
```

Then, I modified the `my-project.cabal` from:

```
executable my-project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , my-project
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

to:

```
executable my-project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , my-project
                     , conduit
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

When I try to `stack build` the following:

```
$cat app/Main.hs

module Main where

import Conduit
import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = someFunc
```

It fails:

```
$stack build
mtl-2.2.1: using precompiled package
primitive-0.6.1.0: using precompiled package
stm-2.4.4.1: using precompiled package
transformers-compat-0.5.1.4: using precompiled package
exceptions-0.8.3: using precompiled package
mmorph-1.0.9: using precompiled package
transformers-base-0.4.4: using precompiled package
monad-control-1.0.1.0: using precompiled package
lifted-base-0.2.3.10: using precompiled package
resourcet-1.1.9: using precompiled package
conduit-1.2.10: configure
conduit-1.2.10: build
conduit-1.2.10: copy/register
my-project-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring my-project-0.1.0.0...
my-project-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library my-project-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Lib.o )
Preprocessing executable 'my-project-exe' for my-project-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/my-project-exe/my-project-exe-tmp/Main.o )

/Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/conduit_sandbox/my-project/app/Main.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Conduit’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Completed 12 action(s).

--  While building package my-project-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/kevinmeredith/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build lib:my-project exe:my-project-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How can I properly add `conduit`?

When adding a library to a `stack` project, do I need to edit both the `stack.yaml` and/or `my-project.cabal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [haddocks for conduit](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.15/package/conduit-1.2.10), notice the module you want to import is not Conduit, it is **Data.Conduit**.

The `Conduit` module comes from the `conduit-combinators` package. If that is the package you would like to use instead, adjust your cabal file as follows and `import Conduit` as before:

```
executable my-project-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , my-project
                     , conduit-combinators
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

The differences between the packages are summarized below (this is taken from [the project's readme](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit#libraries)).

- `conduit-combinators`: provides a large number of common functions built-in
- `conduit`: defines the core datatypes and primitive functions
- `conduit-extra`: adds support for many common low-level operations

Side note: You don't need to make any changes to your `stack.yaml` file as both of these packages are available on stackage.

Comment: Thanks, @Erik. If `conduit-libraries` was not on stackage, then what would I need to do to my `stack.yaml`?

Comment: Editing stack.yaml is required if you wanted to, for instance, depend on a local package, a package available on hackage but not stackage, a package that is located in a git repo, etc. For specific details on how to do this, refer to https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies

Comment: But you had it right in your original question. To get it off hackage, just list the package name in the extra-deps field and stack should download it for you.